# Testing CSS :hover with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

So i've a simple div that when hovered will change its background as defined in my css:

```
.my-class{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.my-class:hover{
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
}
```

I've tried to test this behavior with jasmine but tests keep failing:

```
it "Shadows .soboo-drop-item when hover", ->
      $('.my-class:first').trigger('mouseover')
      expect($('.my-class:first').css('background-color')).toBe("#F2F2F2")
```

> Expected 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' to be '#F2F2F2'

Running `$('.my-class:first').trigger('mouseover')` on console seems not working - background color doesn't change.

Note: Hover JQuery behaviors do respond to `$('#something').trigger('mouseover')`

Im using [Jasminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice), which includes [Jasmine-JQuery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery)

Jasmine-JQuery has a method to test css:

```
expect($('.my-class:first')).toHaveCss({"background-color": "#F2F2F2"})
```

which gives me:

```
Expected '<div class="soboo-service my-class"
service="google"><img
src="http://localhost:3000/img/bookmark-services/google.gif"> Google
Book...</div>' to have css { background-color : '#F2F2F2' }
```

How to check this background?
Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
overed = $($('.my-class:first').trigger('mouseover').html())
expect(overed).toHaveCss({"background-color": "#F2F2F2"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
expect($('.my-class:first')).toHaveCss("background-color","#F2F2F2");